# SEM for within subject data

Tags: multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

My questionnaire is novle,100 listeners listen to 10 sound files and then rate each file on a 12-items likert type scale. So I have 100 participants but 1000 cases. Now my theory is 3 factors can be extracted from 12 items. And I want to use SEM to model the repeated-measured data in lavaan. The general Method factor is added for controlling the common method bias. The model looks like this

```
md = '
F1 =~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
F2 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
F3 =~ z1 + z2 + z3 + z4
Method =~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4
Method ~~ 0*F1
Method ~~ 0*F2
Method ~~ 0*F3
'
```

My question is , is it right to model the repeated-measured data like this? Or other advanced SEM models, such as multilevel SEM?

Comment: I believe your "Method" factor is serving two purposes here. You created it to deal with shared variance relating to all the measurements being Likert-scaled, however, this is exactly the code you would use to create a random intercept to account for repeated measures on the same person. Someone who is a little more versed in sem can speak to whether it can accomplish both things simultaneously, but at the very minimum it is dealing with the repeated measures and expected correlation among the observations.

Comment: Hi, Ruzek, thank you for your comment. Yes, to some extent, I think, that model works. I wonder if there's a theoretically better way to do this. Someone suggested the multilevel SEM. However, multilevel SEM seems to deal with nested design instead of my crossed problem.